# LineRenderer points to world transform coords

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

I'm trying to get enemies to move along definite routes.
I thought the logical solution would be to use the LineRenderer and then translate the local coordinates to world coordinates.

But I honestly have no idea how to do it.

I wish it respected rotations because it would be really cool to be able to do those variable paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to transform local coordinates into world coordinates, you can use a **Transform** within a **GameObject** in code to translate your coordinates.

**Transform** has the function **Transform.TransformPoint(Vector3 position)**, that will use the Transforms position, rotation, and scale, to return a new point in world space.

```
Transform _transform;
Vector3 _originalVector = new Vector3( 1, 1, 1);
Vector3 _transformedVector = _transform.TransformPoint(_originalVector);
```

the **Vector3** _transformedVector will be the position you're looking for in world space.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can just get the local line positions and convert them all to world space using [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

> Transforms position from local space to world space.

and iterate through all points of the line

```
var amount = lineRenderer.GetPositions(out Vector3 [] points);
var worldPoints = new Vector3[amount];
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    worldPoints[i] = lineRenderer.transform.TransformPoint(points[i]);
}
```

---

But alternatively why not simply enable [`LineRenderer.useWorldSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-useWorldSpace.html) and configure your line with world space coordinates, right away?

> If enabled, the lines are defined in world space.
>
> This means the object's position is ignored, and the lines are rendered around world origin.